powerline not working at ubuntu 24.04
My powerline is not showing properly. I'm seeing question marks at the prompt.
I've install these powerline and fonts-powerline and having this at my bashrc
if [ -f /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
   source /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi

These are my locales.
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

I've done the font caching and it seems the font is in place
  badang  jeffry  ~  fc-cache -f
  badang  jeffry  ~  fc-list | grep -i powerline
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/PowerlineSymbols.otf: PowerlineSymbols:style=Medium


Am I missing something here?

This question is similar to: How can I install and use powerline plugin?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should change the fonts in the config for your terminal emulator as well
In the default ubuntu terminal - you should do Edit -> Preferences -> Profiles
and use the newly installed fonts.

In addition to the answer by @hold-me, I had to previously run:
sudo fc-cache -vf

